# SetActive(true) not working inside a coroutine

Tags: unity-game-engine, coroutine

I am using coroutines to manage cooldowns for powerups in my game. When the player collides with a powerup they will get the effect and a cooldown will start so they can't use it again for a certain amount of time.

I am using coroutines to manage these cooldowns - setting the gameObject to false, waiting for the cooldown, then setting the `gameObject` back to true.

My code:

```c#
IEnumerator RespawnTime ()
{
    gameObject.SetActive(false);
    Debug.Log("disabled");

    yield return new WaitForSeconds(3f);

    gameObject.SetActive(true);
    Debug.Log("enabled");
}

private void OnCollisionEnter2D (Collision2D collision)
{
    // Health stuff goes in here.
    Debug.Log("Health regen!");

    // Start cooldown
    StartCoroutine(RespawnTime());
}
```

However, the gameObject is never activated again once disabled. I don't think the problem is with the yield as commenting out the SetActive statements results in both debug messages being displayed at the correct times.

Edit:

Sorry, I didn't clarify. I know coroutines don't run on disabled `GameObjects`. I made a `PowerUpManager` script and it didn't work. Code:

In the `PowerUp` script, in the `OnCollisionEnter2D` method

```c#
StartCoroutines(PowerUpManager.RespawnTime(gameObject))
```

In the `PowerUpManager` script

```c#
public static IEnumerator RespawnTime(GameObject powerUp)
{
    powerUp.SetActive(false);

    yield return new WaitForSeconds(3f);

    powerUp.SetActive(true);
}
```

Comment: `coroutines` for disabled objects are disabled as well. You have to run this coroutine in other gameobject.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The moment you call

```c#
gameObject.SetActive(false);
```

this object does not receive the `Update` message anymore and thus also doesn't execute the [Coroutine](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Coroutines.html) further.

> Coroutines are also stopped when the MonoBehaviour is destroyed or **when the `GameObject` it is attached to is disabled.**

---

The reason your second attempt doesn't work is: You still are calling `StartCoroutine` on the same `GameObject` so the Coroutine of the `PowerUpManager` class is now executed **on your `GameObject`** => same effect.

If you really want to go with the `PowerUpManager` you would need a Singleton instance and call `StartCoroutine` on that instance like e.g.

In `PowerUpManager` have

```c#
public static PowerUpManager Instance;

private void Awake()
{
    Instance = this;
}
```

then you can call from your script

```c#
PowerUpManager.Instance.StartCoroutine(PowerUpManager.RespawnTime(gameObject));
```

---

In your simple case where there is no smooth moving etc required but only a simple delay I would suggest rather using [`Invoke`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.Invoke.html) with your desired delay. This will also be executed on a disabled or inactive `GameObject`.

```c#
private void EnableAfterCooldown()
{
    gameObject.SetActive(true);
    Debug.Log("enabled");
}

private void OnCollisionEnter2D (Collision2D collision)
{
    // Health stuff goes in here.
    Debug.Log("Health regen!");

    gameObject.SetActive(false);
    Invoke("EnableAfterCooldown", 3f);
}
```

Comment: Fantastic! The invoke method worked perfectly. Thanks alot :).

Comment: Also see the upate about a static Coroutine ;)

Comment: Yep I saw it. Stackoverflow is awesome :D. Thanks for your help man.

Answer (score 1):

If you deactivate the game object, all its components get disabled as well, so the Coroutine stops being invoked.

What you can do, is to separate the Coroutine for the cool down and the script that checks the collision, in 2 separate scripts.

Let’s call the `Cooldown.cs` and `Powerup.cs`.
Then, have them cross referenced in each other. 
In powerup.cs you have

```c#
private void OnCollisionEnter2D (Collision2D collision)
{
    // Health stuff goes in here.
    Debug.Log("Health regen!");
    // Start cooldown
    Cooldown cd = gameObject.GetComponent<cooldown>();
    cd.CooldownCoroutine();
}
```

In Cooldown.cs:

```c#
IEnumerator RespawnTime ()
{
     Powerup pu = gameObject.GetComponent<Powerup>()
     pu.SetActive(false);
     Debug.Log("disabled");
     yield return new WaitForSeconds(3f);
     pu.SetActive(true);
     Debug.Log("enabled");
}

public void CooldownCoroutine()
{
    // Health stuff goes in here.
    Debug.Log("Health regen!");
    // Start cooldown
    StartCoroutine(RespawnTime());
}
```

This way you don’t disable the whole object, but only the script that checks for collisions.

Comment: Ah so thats how you would properly do it! I'm using invoke now, but thanks for clarifying why my attempt with 2 GameObjects didn't work. Have a good one! :)

Comment: +1 This is indeed a good alternative in general **if** you don't want to disable the entire `GameObject`. Might however in some cases be more overhead for example if you need to disable **all** other components like `MeshRenderer`, `Collider` etc on the that `GameObject` .. since OP's usecase is a permanently respawning collectable item

Answer (score 0):

Coroutines do not run on disabled game objects!

You should run this on another game object.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't clarify I had tried this - my bad. I've updated my question.

Comment: @Wzrd I don't think you're allowed to have static coroutines. You should pass an instance of the PowerUpManager to script you want to run it from. Or make it a singleton.

Comment: Thanks to derHugo I've solved the problem, but I'll double check that and bear it in mind the the future. Thanks and have a great day. :).